# Can't repaint my JFrame/JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, repaint

I have created a program that just moves a ball across a screen. I used to have it all in one class, but decided that it looked too messy so I split it up into three different classes: Main... initializes everything, Game... which paints everything and is a JPanel, and AL which is a KeyListener (which is also where the problem is). The problem is that I can't get the program to repaint from my AL class no matter what I try to pass into it. Can anyone help with this? Here are my three classes:

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    static Game game;
    static JFrame frame;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    game = new Game();
    frame = new JFrame();

    frame.getContentPane().add(game);
    frame.addKeyListener(new AL(game, frame));
    frame.setTitle("Game");
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
}
```

-

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    int x, y, xCoord, yCoord;
    private Image dbImage;
    private Graphics dbg;
    JFrame frame;

public void changeCoord() {
    x += xCoord;
    y += yCoord;
    if (x <= 20) {
        x = 20;
    }
    if (x >= 480) {
        x = 480;
    }
    if (y <= 40) {
        y = 40;
    }
    if (y >= 480) {
        y = 480;
    }
}

public void setXCoord(int xcoord) {
    xCoord = xcoord;
}

public void setYCoord(int ycoord) {
    yCoord = ycoord;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game game = new Game();
    Thread t = new Thread(game);
    t.start();
}

public Game() {
    x = 250;
    y = 250;

}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillOval(x, y, 15, 15);
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
    dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
    paintComponent(dbg);
    g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            changeCoord();
            Thread.sleep(30);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

}
```

-

```
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class AL extends KeyAdapter {
    Game game;
    JFrame frame;

public AL(Game game, JFrame frame) {
    this.game = game;
    this.frame = frame;
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    if (keyCode == e.VK_LEFT) {
        game.setXCoord(-1);
    }
    if (keyCode == e.VK_RIGHT) {
        game.setXCoord(+1);
    }
    if (keyCode == e.VK_UP) {
        game.setYCoord(-1);
    }
    if (keyCode == e.VK_DOWN) {
        game.setYCoord(+1);
    }
    game.repaint();
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    if (keyCode == e.VK_LEFT) {
        game.setXCoord(0);
    }
    if (keyCode == e.VK_RIGHT) {
        game.setXCoord(0);
    }
    if (keyCode == e.VK_UP) {
        game.setYCoord(0);
    }
    if (keyCode == e.VK_DOWN) {
        game.setYCoord(0);
    }
    game.repaint();

}

}
```

Comment: Why is your drawing code so unusual? For instance, why override paint and directly call paintComponent? I have no idea what your code is doing there, but it doesn't look healthy at all, and you're not even calling the super's paint method. I suggest that first and foremost, you get rid of that dangerous paint method override, and do all drawing, in a much simpler manner, within paintComponent, including calling the `super.paintComponent(g);` method first within that method.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels Thanks, I'll try it, but could you explain to me why overriding the paint method is so "dangerous"? And why is calling the super.paintComponent good?

Comment: MadProgrammer's got things well in hand below.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That's just an illusion, it's barely maintained chaos ... business as usual

Comment: @MadProgrammer: your illusions and barely maintained chaos are head and shoulders above the knowledge and formed thoughts that I hold in my brain. Keep fomenting the chaos please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with the obvious....

This is problematic...

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillOval(x, y, 15, 15);
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
    dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
    paintComponent(dbg);
    g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
}
```

There's no need to implement double buffering in Swing components, they already are.  Also, you're breaking the painting contract, by not call the paint methods super methods

The whole thing should be...

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillOval(x, y, 15, 15);
}
```

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

`KeyListener` is well known for been problematic.  It will only raise key events if the component it registered to is focuable AND has keyboard focus.  A `JPanel` by default, is not focusable.  Before you run of and try and make it focusable (and get bitterly disappointed), you should be using the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead, which was designed to over come the limitations of `KeyListener`

As a basic example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new Game());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Game extends JPanel {

        int x, y, xCoord, yCoord;

        public Game() {
            x = 250;
            y = 250;
            addKeyBinding(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, "move.left", new MoveAction(this, -1, 0));
            addKeyBinding(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, "move.right", new MoveAction(this, 1, 0));
            addKeyBinding(KeyEvent.VK_UP, "move.up", new MoveAction(this, 0, -1));
            addKeyBinding(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, "move.down", new MoveAction(this, 0, 1));
        }

        protected void addKeyBinding(int keyCode, String name, Action action) {
            addKeyBinding(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0), name, action);
        }

        protected void addKeyBinding(KeyStroke keyStroke, String name, Action action) {
            InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();
            inputMap.put(keyStroke, name);
            actionMap.put(name, action);
        }

        public void changeCoord() {
            x += xCoord;
            y += yCoord;
            if (x <= 20) {
                x = 20;
            }
            if (x >= 480) {
                x = 480;
            }
            if (y <= 40) {
                y = 40;
            }
            if (y >= 480) {
                y = 480;
            }

            repaint();
        }

        public void setXCoord(int xcoord) {
            xCoord = xcoord;
            changeCoord();
        }

        public void setYCoord(int ycoord) {
            yCoord = ycoord;
            changeCoord();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(480, 480);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 15, 15);
        }

    }

    public class MoveAction extends AbstractAction {

        private int xDelta;
        private int yDelta;

        // I'd prefer an interface with just the "move" methods, but
        // that's more time I don't have
        private Game game;

        public MoveAction(Game game, int xDelta, int yDelta) {
            this.xDelta = xDelta;
            this.yDelta = yDelta;
            this.game = game;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            game.setXCoord(xDelta);
            game.setYCoord(yDelta);
        }

    }
}
```

But, wait, that isn't exactly what you want (trust me, I'm an anoymouse person on the Internet ;)), a better example might be...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new Game());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public enum Direction {
        UP,
        LEFT,
        DOWN,
        RIGHT;
    }

    public class Game extends JPanel {

        int x, y, xCoord, yCoord;

        private Set<Direction> movement;

        public Game() {
            x = 250;
            y = 250;

            movement = new HashSet<>(4);

            addKeyPressedBinding(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, "left.pressed", new MoveAction(movement, Direction.LEFT, true));
            addKeyReleasedBinding(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, "left.released", new MoveAction(movement, Direction.LEFT, false));

            addKeyPressedBinding(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, "right.pressed", new MoveAction(movement, Direction.RIGHT, true));
            addKeyReleasedBinding(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, "right.released", new MoveAction(movement, Direction.RIGHT, false));

            addKeyPressedBinding(KeyEvent.VK_UP, "up.pressed", new MoveAction(movement, Direction.UP, true));
            addKeyReleasedBinding(KeyEvent.VK_UP, "up.released", new MoveAction(movement, Direction.UP, false));

            addKeyPressedBinding(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, "down.pressed", new MoveAction(movement, Direction.DOWN, true));
            addKeyReleasedBinding(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, "down.released", new MoveAction(movement, Direction.DOWN, false));

            Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    changeCoord();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        protected void addKeyBinding(int keyCode, String name, Action action) {
            addKeyBinding(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0), name, action);
        }

        protected void addKeyPressedBinding(int keyCode, String name, Action action) {
            addKeyBinding(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0, false), name, action);
        }

        protected void addKeyReleasedBinding(int keyCode, String name, Action action) {
            addKeyBinding(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0, true), name, action);
        }

        protected void addKeyBinding(KeyStroke keyStroke, String name, Action action) {
            InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();
            inputMap.put(keyStroke, name);
            actionMap.put(name, action);
        }

        public void changeCoord() {

            if (movement.contains(Direction.UP)) {
                y--;
            } else if (movement.contains(Direction.DOWN)) {
                y++;
            }
            if (movement.contains(Direction.LEFT)) {
                x--;
            } else if (movement.contains(Direction.RIGHT)) {
                x++;
            }

            x += xCoord;
            y += yCoord;
            if (x <= 20) {
                x = 20;
            }
            if (x >= 480) {
                x = 480;
            }
            if (y <= 40) {
                y = 40;
            }
            if (y >= 480) {
                y = 480;
            }

            repaint();
        }

        public void setXCoord(int xcoord) {
            xCoord = xcoord;
            changeCoord();
        }

        public void setYCoord(int ycoord) {
            yCoord = ycoord;
            changeCoord();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(480, 480);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 15, 15);
        }

    }

    public class MoveAction extends AbstractAction {

        private Set<Direction> movement;
        private Direction direction;
        private boolean pressed;

        public MoveAction(Set<Direction> movement, Direction direction, boolean pressed) {
            this.movement = movement;
            this.direction = direction;
            this.pressed = pressed;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (pressed) {
                movement.add(direction);
            } else {
                movement.remove(direction);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

What this does is simply activates a flag when a key is pressed (and deactivates it when it's released), then in a Swing `Timer`, we check which keys are "active" and update the location of the ball.

What this does is, eliminates the key "stutter" which is caused by the OS when a key is first pressed and held. A delay is inserted between the first key and the repeated key events.  Instead, we just turn the flag on and off as we like.

It also allows you to move in two directions at the same time (horizontally and vertically)

Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks! Everything seems to be in order except for two things... Now that I run it... I can't turn the background Black anymore. The second thing is that I'm not entirely sure about what you mean by painting contract. Why exactly is it wrong no to call it and what does it do when you do call it?

Comment: 1- Use `setBackground` on the `JPanel`, it will fill it with what ever color you want; 2- Paint is made up of a series of chained methods calls, which together, work to generate the output, but failing to maintain this call chain (or contract) you are running the risk of introducing painting artifacts, which are difficult to trace and diagnose. Unless you are really, really, REALLY sure you know what you're doing, best not to mess with it, because it may not effect your current component, but may effect others or blow up at some random point in the future