# How can I get Animation to run with KeyBoard input in JAVA?

Tags: java, swing, awt, keylistener

today's problem rattling my mind is this, I'm trying to draw a red rectangle that moves whenever the user presses space. The problem is that whenever I press space the rectangle doesn't move. Any ideas why and how I could fix this problem?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Animation extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener{

    int x = 0, y = 0, velx=0;

    public Animation(){
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Animation Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        Animation a = new Animation();
        frame.add(a);

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(x, 50, 30, 20);
        }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        x = x + velx;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if(keyCode == e.VK_SPACE){
            velx = 2;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: Why did you import awt and swing? Use either one or the other. Also if you add the "awt" and "swing" tags to your question you might get more feedback :)

Comment: Yeah basically as per the answer below `actionPerformed` is unlikely to ever be being called. You need to put the update logic in the `KeyListener` events.

Comment: [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made the following changes to your code. Pressing back space should now move the rectangle.

1. Add the KeyListener to JFrame.
2. Changes to KeyBoard event listener method.

**CODE:**

```
public class Animation extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener{

int x = 0, y = 0, velx=0;

public Animation(){
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Animation Test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    Animation a = new Animation();
    frame.add(a);
    frame.repaint();
    frame.addKeyListener(a);

}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(x, 50, 30, 20);
 }

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    x = x + velx;
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    if(keyCode == e.VK_SPACE){
        velx = 2;
        x = x + velx;
    }
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Comment: [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) and [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html); There's no need for `paintComponent` to be public

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `KeyListener` is just a pain in the ... code.

It will only respond to key events when the component it is registered to is focusable AND has keyboard focus.  The problem is, focus changes and it's a pain to manage and control.

Instead, you should be using the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which was designed to help solve this problem

There are plenty of examples of key bindings on SO, maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800282/cant-repaint-my-jframe-jpanel/34800437#34800437) might help