# KeyBindings seem to work improperly and don't know why | Java

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

**Problem**

---

I am making a game for a final project in a class of mine and I am working on the Keybinding. The Keybindings work just not how they should. Let me explain:

So the objective is to move your character one "square" at a time while moving towards the exit(black dot). Each time you hit the keybinding for the specified direction (A, S, D, W) it should check the "terrain" and move you to that if it is "floor".

**Side-Note:** I have yet to add removing terrain because I need the movement to work properly first.

Back to the explanation:
So the biggest problem is that when I hit a keybinding for the first time it moves the character three "squares" away from the original position. Then any movement after that is random and will sometimes put the player out of bounds. I have it set up so it prints out the location of the player every time a keybinding is activated (see below code). I have a feeling I did something wrong with the keybinding process as this is my first time keybinding something. 

Here one of the print outs that my program gave me for my character's movement:

```
E:\StackOverflow\KeyBindings>java gamePanelMain
Player Start X: 0
Player Start Y: 0

Direction: Right, New X: 3
Direction: Right, New Y: 0

Direction: Right, New X: 9
Direction: Right, New Y: 0

Direction: Right, New X: 12
Direction: Right, New Y: 0

Direction: Down, New X: 12
Direction: Down, New Y: 3

Direction: Down, New X: 12
Direction: Down, New Y: 6

Direction: Down, New X: 12
Direction: Down, New Y: 8

Direction: Left, New X: 10
Direction: Left, New Y: 8

Direction: Left, New X: 7
Direction: Left, New Y: 8

Direction: Left, New X: 4
Direction: Left, New Y: 8

Direction: Down, New X: 4
Direction: Down, New Y: 11

Direction: Down, New X: 4
Direction: Down, New Y: 13

Direction: Down, New X: 4
Direction: Down, New Y: 17

Direction: Right, New X: 7
Direction: Right, New Y: 17

Direction: Right, New X: 17
Direction: Right, New Y: 17

Direction: Right, New X: 20
Direction: Right, New Y: 17

Direction: Right, New X: 23
Direction: Right, New Y: 17

Direction: Down, New X: 23
Direction: Down, New Y: 20

Direction: Down, New X: 23
Direction: Down, New Y: 23

Direction: Up, New X: 23
Direction: Up, New Y: 21

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 24
        at gamePanel.right(gamePanel.java:259)
        at gamePanel.changeCoord(gamePanel.java:192)
        at gamePanel$1.actionPerformed(gamePanel.java:46)
        at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

As you can see it is completely random and the movement is not connected to a random generator or anything like that. Also I have yet to add in the code to check for out of bounds, but I am more worried about getting this movement correct first.

Now I looked at a post on keybinding ([Can't repaint my JFrame/JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800282/cant-repaint-my-jframe-jpanel/34800437#34800437)) and tried to apply the technique to my game for the keybinding operation. I don't know what I did wrong is part of the problem.

Here is the code I added just for the keybinding:

```
public enum Direction{
        UP,
        LEFT,
        DOWN,
        RIGHT;
    }

    private Set<Direction>movement;

    public gamePanel()
    {
        setBounds(115,93,480,480);//sets the size and location of gamePanel (x,y,w,h)
        setFocusable(true);



        movement = new HashSet<>(4);

        addKeyPressedBinding(KeyEvent.VK_A, "left.pressed", new MoveAction(movement, Direction.LEFT, true));
        addKeyReleasedBinding(KeyEvent.VK_A, "left.released", new MoveAction(movement, Direction.LEFT, false));

        addKeyPressedBinding(KeyEvent.VK_D, "right.pressed", new MoveAction(movement, Direction.RIGHT, true));
        addKeyReleasedBinding(KeyEvent.VK_D, "right.released", new MoveAction(movement, Direction.RIGHT, false));

        addKeyPressedBinding(KeyEvent.VK_W, "up.pressed", new MoveAction(movement, Direction.UP, true));
        addKeyReleasedBinding(KeyEvent.VK_W, "up.released", new MoveAction(movement, Direction.UP, false));

        addKeyPressedBinding(KeyEvent.VK_S, "down.pressed", new MoveAction(movement, Direction.DOWN, true));
        addKeyReleasedBinding(KeyEvent.VK_S, "down.released", new MoveAction(movement, Direction.DOWN, false));

        Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                changeCoord();

            }
        });

        timer.start();

        System.out.println("Player Start X: " + pcX);
        System.out.println("Player Start Y: " + pcY + "\n");


    }

    protected void addKeyBinding(int keyCode, String name, Action action){
        addKeyBinding(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0), name, action);
    }
        protected void addKeyPressedBinding(int keyCode, String name, Action action) {
            addKeyBinding(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0, false), name, action);
        }

        protected void addKeyReleasedBinding(int keyCode, String name, Action action) {
            addKeyBinding(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0, true), name, action);
        }

        protected void addKeyBinding(KeyStroke keyStroke, String name, Action action) {
            InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();
            inputMap.put(keyStroke, name);
            actionMap.put(name, action);
        }   


    //Later in the code after the generation and painting of the map...............

              public void changeCoord() {

            if (movement.contains(Direction.UP)) {
                up();//checks position and moves player if it is "safe"
                System.out.println("Direction: Up, New X: " + pcX);
                System.out.println("Direction: Up, New Y: " + pcY + "\n");
            } else if (movement.contains(Direction.DOWN)) {
                down();//checks position and moves player if it is "safe"
                System.out.println("Direction: Down, New X: " + pcX);
                System.out.println("Direction: Down, New Y: " + pcY + "\n");                
            }
            if (movement.contains(Direction.LEFT)) {
                left();//checks position and moves player if it is "safe"
                System.out.println("Direction: Left, New X: " + pcX);
                System.out.println("Direction: Left, New Y: " + pcY + "\n");                
            } else if (movement.contains(Direction.RIGHT)) {
                right();//checks position and moves player if it is "safe"
                System.out.println("Direction: Right, New X: " + pcX);
                System.out.println("Direction: Right, New Y: " + pcY + "\n");               
            }

            repaint();
        }

        public class MoveAction extends AbstractAction{
            private Set<Direction> movement;
            private Direction direction;
            private boolean pressed;

        public MoveAction(Set<Direction> movement, Direction direction, boolean pressed) {
            this.movement = movement;
            this.direction = direction;
            this.pressed = pressed;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (pressed) {
                movement.add(direction);
            } else {
                movement.remove(direction);
            }
        }           
        }
```

**Question**
Am I doing something wrong with the keybinding process? And if so how do I fix it? If not what have I done wrong?

Here is some working code if you would like to mess around with it yourself:

**Main Class**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class gamePanelMain{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();    
        gamePanel panel = new gamePanel();
        frame.add(panel);       
        frame.setSize(520,540);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        panel.mapGen();

    }//end main
}
```

**Code that does everything**

```
import java.awt.*;

    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.awt.image.*;
    import javax.swing.Timer;



        public class gamePanel extends JPanel 
        {

        public enum Direction{
            UP,
            LEFT,
            DOWN,
            RIGHT;
        }

        private Set<Direction>movement;

        public gamePanel()
        {
            setBounds(115,93,480,480);//sets the size and location of gamePanel (x,y,w,h)
            setFocusable(true);



            movement = new HashSet<>(4);

            addKeyPressedBinding(KeyEvent.VK_A, "left.pressed", new MoveAction(movement, Direction.LEFT, true));
            addKeyReleasedBinding(KeyEvent.VK_A, "left.released", new MoveAction(movement, Direction.LEFT, false));

            addKeyPressedBinding(KeyEvent.VK_D, "right.pressed", new MoveAction(movement, Direction.RIGHT, true));
            addKeyReleasedBinding(KeyEvent.VK_D, "right.released", new MoveAction(movement, Direction.RIGHT, false));

            addKeyPressedBinding(KeyEvent.VK_W, "up.pressed", new MoveAction(movement, Direction.UP, true));
            addKeyReleasedBinding(KeyEvent.VK_W, "up.released", new MoveAction(movement, Direction.UP, false));

            addKeyPressedBinding(KeyEvent.VK_S, "down.pressed", new MoveAction(movement, Direction.DOWN, true));
            addKeyReleasedBinding(KeyEvent.VK_S, "down.released", new MoveAction(movement, Direction.DOWN, false));

            Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    changeCoord();

                }
            });

            timer.start();

            System.out.println("Player Start X: " + pcX);
            System.out.println("Player Start Y: " + pcY + "\n");


        }

        protected void addKeyBinding(int keyCode, String name, Action action){
            addKeyBinding(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0), name, action);
        }
            protected void addKeyPressedBinding(int keyCode, String name, Action action) {
                addKeyBinding(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0, false), name, action);
            }

            protected void addKeyReleasedBinding(int keyCode, String name, Action action) {
                addKeyBinding(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0, true), name, action);
            }

            protected void addKeyBinding(KeyStroke keyStroke, String name, Action action) {
                InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
                ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();
                inputMap.put(keyStroke, name);
                actionMap.put(name, action);
            }   

        private Random tGenerator = new Random();//initialize a random number generator

        int tmin = 1;
        int tmax = 20;

        int floor = 0;  //initializes the variable floor to zero for later use
        int dirt = 1;  //initializes the variable dirt to one for later use
        int stone = 2; //initializes the variable stone to two for later use

        int width = 24; // width of playing area
        int height = 24; //height of playing area
        int x, y; // my x & y variables for coordinates


        int[][] coords = new int[width][height]; //my array that I want to store the coordinates for later use in painting


        int[] terrain = {floor, dirt, stone}; //my terrain that will determine the color of the paint


        public void mapGen() //what should mark/generate the JPanel
        {

            for(x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {

                for(y = 0; y < height; y++)
                {

                    int t = tGenerator.nextInt(tmax - tmin + 1) + tmin; // random generator for terrain

                    if(t <= 10)
                    {
                        coords[x][y] = terrain[floor]; //should mark the coordinates as floor

                    }

                    if(t >= 12 && t <=16)
                    {
                        coords[x][y] = terrain[stone]; //should mark the coordinates as stone
                    }

                    if(t >=17 && t <= 19)
                    {
                        coords[x][y] = terrain[dirt]; //should mark the coordinates as dirt
                    }
                }
            }
                        coords[0][0] = terrain[0]; // sets coordinate 0,0 to floor 
                        coords[23][23] = terrain[0]; // sets coordinate 24,24 to floor 

        }//end mapGen


        public int pcY = 0;
        public int pcX = 0;     

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)//what will paint each 20x20 square on the grid what it is assigned
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);


        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {

                for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                {   

                    if(coords[x][y] == terrain[floor])// paints floor color at marked coordinates
                    {
                        g.setColor(new Color(249,249,249));
                        g.fillRect((x*20), (y*20), 20, 20); 

                    }

                    if(coords[x][y] == terrain[dirt])// paints dirt color at marked coordinates
                    {
                        g.setColor(new Color(121,85,58));
                        g.fillRect((x*20), (y*20), 20, 20);
                    }

                    if(coords[x][y] == terrain[stone])// paints stone color at marked coordinates
                    {
                        g.setColor(new Color(143,143,143));
                        g.fillRect((x*20),(y*20),20,20);
                    }

                }
            }

            g.setColor(Color.red);//creates the player "model"
            g.fillOval((pcX*20),(pcY*20),20,20);

            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillOval((23*20),(23*20),20,20);

        }//end paintComponent

            public void changeCoord() {

                if (movement.contains(Direction.UP)) {
                    up();
                    System.out.println("Direction: Up, New X: " + pcX);
                    System.out.println("Direction: Up, New Y: " + pcY + "\n");
                } else if (movement.contains(Direction.DOWN)) {
                    down();
                    System.out.println("Direction: Down, New X: " + pcX);
                    System.out.println("Direction: Down, New Y: " + pcY + "\n");                
                }
                if (movement.contains(Direction.LEFT)) {
                    left();
                    System.out.println("Direction: Left, New X: " + pcX);
                    System.out.println("Direction: Left, New Y: " + pcY + "\n");                
                } else if (movement.contains(Direction.RIGHT)) {
                    right();
                    System.out.println("Direction: Right, New X: " + pcX);
                    System.out.println("Direction: Right, New Y: " + pcY + "\n");               
                }

                repaint();
            }

            public class MoveAction extends AbstractAction{
                private Set<Direction> movement;
                private Direction direction;
                private boolean pressed;

            public MoveAction(Set<Direction> movement, Direction direction, boolean pressed) {
                this.movement = movement;
                this.direction = direction;
                this.pressed = pressed;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (pressed) {
                    movement.add(direction);
                } else {
                    movement.remove(direction);
                }
            }           
            }


        public void up(){
                if(coords[pcX][pcY--] == terrain[floor]){
                    coords[pcX][pcY] = coords[pcX][pcY--];
                }

                else if(coords[pcX][pcY--] == terrain[dirt]){
                    coords[pcX][pcY] = coords[pcX][pcY--];
                }

                else if(coords[pcX][pcY--] == terrain[stone]){
                    coords[pcX][pcY] = coords[pcX][pcY--];
                }

            }

        public void down(){

                if(coords[pcX][pcY++] == terrain[floor]){
                    pcY++;
                }

                else if(coords[pcX][pcY++] == terrain[dirt]){
                    pcY++;
                }

                else if(coords[pcX][pcY++] == terrain[stone]){
                    pcY++;
                }           

            }

            public void right(){

                if(coords[pcX++][pcY] == terrain[floor]){
                    pcX += pcX+1;
                }

                else if(coords[pcX++][pcY]  == terrain[dirt]){
                    pcX++;
                }

                else if(coords[pcX++][pcY]  == terrain[stone]){
                    pcX++;
                }           

            }

            public void left(){

                if(coords[pcX--][pcY] == terrain[floor]){
                    pcX--;
                }           

                else if(coords[pcX--][pcY] == terrain[dirt]){
                    pcX--;
                }

                else if(coords[pcX--][pcY] == terrain[stone]){
                    pcX--;
                }           
            }   
    }// end gamePanel
```

**Please** try and keep all explanations as "dumbed" down as possible as I am still learning and do not understand all of the coding lingo quite yet.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Oops, sorry let me reformat for you real quick

Comment: Possible duplicate of [KeyListener, keyPressed versus keyTyped](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071757/keylistener-keypressed-versus-keytyped)

Comment: @bns I have looked at that post and it does not seem to address my problem. Again I am new to keybinding so maybe I am missing something

Comment: Your right() method seems to have multiple issues that are causing this issue. Firstly, you are doing no checks that ensures that you are within bounds, especially the pcX variable. And there's a line that looks VERY wrong to me: `pcX += pcX + 1`. This is going to increment the value of pcX by itself + 1. So, if pcX is 4, then it will become 9 after this line. Seems strange to me. As well as the multiple uses of ++ in there. You should do your incrementing or decrementing first, then use the amended variable. Makes it far easier to debug.

Comment: @ManoDestra In the post I said I was going to worry about bounds once I got the movement to work. But I do agree that the pcX += pcX +1 is not proper. Don't know why I did that

Comment: It's all going to be part of your issue. If you correct some of these other issues, then your primary issue may become more transparent. You've got multiple errors here that are muddying the waters, so to speak. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(coords[pcX][pcY++] == terrain[floor]){
    pcY++;
}

else if(coords[pcX][pcY++] == terrain[dirt]){
    pcY++;
}

else if(coords[pcX][pcY++] == terrain[stone]){
    pcY++;
}
```

> I hit a keybinding for the first time it moves the character three "squares" away from the original position

You use "pcY++" multiple times. Every time you use that variable in the if statement the variable gets incremented.

So you get random results because you invoke a random number of if statements each time you do a move.

Don't use "++" on a variable in your if statements. You only increment your variable when it passes the test.

Also, you don't need up/down/left/right methods. The point of using a common Action is to specify how the Action affects the x/y location. So the `changeCoord()`could look something like:

```
public void changeCoord()
{
    int potentialX = pcX;
    int potentialY = pcY;

    if (movement.contains(Direction.LEFT)) potentialX--;
    if (movement.contains(Direction.RIGHT)) potentialX++;
    if (movement.contains(Direction.UP)) potentialY--;
    if (movement.contains(Direction.DOWN)) potentialY++;

    if (isValidMove(potentialX, potentially)
    {
        pcX = potentialX;
        pcY = potentialY;
    }

    repaint();
}


private boolean isValidMove(int potentialX, int potentialY)
{
    if (cords[potentialX][potentialY] == terrain[floor])
        return true;

    ...

    return false;
}
```

Also, I'm not a big fan of using the enums. You are limited to only up/down/lef/right. What happens if you ever want to add the ability to move diagonally? Check out the `KeyboardAnimation` example in  [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/). The Action in that example allows you to specify a point to move to. So you don't need if/else checks for the enum you just use values specified in the Point to determine the next location.

Comment: So how do I check the next "square" ?

Comment: @TheMrBaggins, you use a separate variable. See edit.

Comment: Alrighty will try it out when I am back on my pc. Thanks for your help

Comment: so i am a little confused on your example. mostly the "if(isValidMove(potentialX, potentially)" is that creating something or what is it doing?

Comment: The point is you don't know if the move is valid. So first you create a temporary variables for the x/y locations and calculate where you hope to move to. Then you check if the move if valid. If it is valid then you update the permanent x/y values and make the move, otherwise you don't do anything.

Comment: okay, so the "private boolean........." is outside of changeCoord() right. Also should I just scrap all the keybinding stuff I did previously?

Comment: Correct, it is just a method that determines if the move is valid. The key binding code should still be valid. The problem was your logic for moving the player. You had 4 separate test conditions (up/down/left/right). I showed you simple code to combine the 4 into a single method.

Comment: If it would not be too much trouble could you show me an example of implementing this using my code I provided. I have been sitting here for 2 hours trying to get a grasp on this but it just makes no sense.

Comment: Well I have no idea what is confusing you. You have been given multiple working examples of how to change the x/y location of a component/object. So you have working examples to look at. The difference with your code is that you can't automatically update the x/y value every time the key is pressed. So you first need to test the potential x/y location to see if it is valid. I updated my answer with the possible `changeCoord(.)` method you can use. The key is you can only update the x/y value if the move is valid.

Comment: Thx for all your help. all I was missing was the "movement.Direction....." part.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using addKeyPressedBinding and addKeyReleasedBinding.
That way its going to trigger the action twice, once when the user presses they key and once when the user releases it.

I don't think that's the behavior you are expecting.

Comment: it wont do anything for that action.
Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071757/keylistener-keypressed-versus-keytyped to learn about different triggers

Comment: I tried taking away the addKeyReleasedBinding and when I pressed a "D" once and let go the character kept moving

Comment: please read the link I sent earlier. If you wanted the action to be performed while the key is pressed, and can be triggered more than once (ex: a gun that keeps firing) use keypressed.

If you want the action to be performed once when you release the key use keyreleased.

If you want the action to be performed after a character is typed (such as Shift+7 to type the character &) then use keytyped

Comment: Okay so correct me if I am wrong: keypressed= constant action while being pressed, keyreleased = action occurs once, and keytyped = action performed only after the key is pressed and released

Comment: keytyped = action performed after a character is sent. That means if you press alt+164 the action will be triggered only once for the character ñ instead of  four (for the alt key, for the 1, the 6  and the 4).

Comment: so do I have to have it set up with two keys being pressed or can I have it happen wit just one. Also how would the set up look like. I tried to implement it but it did not work. Probably did something wrong

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12295794)

Comment: @kommradHomer, when I posted the answer the question was about what's wrong in the keybinding process. I think it's more important that he understands the difference between those methods and what's exactly wrong with his approach, than just give him the working code.
He also needs to pay attention to ++ and -- operators and validate inbounds of the map. So should we just provide the working code or explain where are the faults so beginners could learn and improve? If it's just the code, I would gladly edit my answer and comments but I don't think TheMrBaggins will learn from that.

Comment: `You shouldn't be using addKeyPressedBinding and addKeyReleasedBinding.` - you do need both. A Timer is used to make the animation smooth if a key is held down. So the "pressed" is used to set the direction and the "released" is used to cancel the direction.